# Not sure why footnotes are going off the page

Tags: line-breaking, footnotes

I can't find out why my footnotes are running off the page on the right margin.

My beginning code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{indent first} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{bigfoot} 
\DeclareNewFootnote{default} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document} 
\section{Introduction} 
Null. \footnote {Himmelstein, Thorne, Warren, Woolhandler, \underline{Medical Bankruptcy in the United States, 2007: Results of a National Study}, \textit{The American Journal of Medicine}, 2009.} \\

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you complete your code so we have a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. And please make sure it compiles! (This doesn't even when I complete it.)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem even when I add `\lipsum[1]` (with the `lipsum` package) as a footnote.

Comment: Hi, sorry. I just started learning it so I just looked up different ways to change the margins and I included it in the code. If there's a good way to start the code fresh, please let me know as well.

Comment: We need code which reproduces the problem. Your code does not. We want something we can cut-paste-compile to see the issue you are seeing. Even when I complete your code so it compiles and add a looooonnnng footnote, I don't see the problem you are describing. So all I can say is that something in the code you haven't posted must be causing the problem. And very likely that is all anybody can say. Please read the link I posted which explains how to produce an MWE.

Comment: You can ***edit*** your question to add the code.

Comment: Highlight the code and click the `{}` button in the editor to indent by 4 spaces. Then it will be formatted as code in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You should really consider using `bibtex` or `biblatex`/`biber` to manage citations and references. However, if you really insist on doing this manually, then you need a more intelligent underlining macro which allows line breaks. `soul` can do this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{default}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
  \section{Introduction}
  Null. \footnote {Himmelstein, Thorne, Warren, Woolhandler, \ul{Medical Bankruptcy in the United States, 2007: Results of a National Study}, \textit{The American Journal of Medicine}, 2009.}
\end{document}
```

[image: underline with soul]